# Installing tabulizer package in R

Tags: r, package, tabulizer

I am using R version 3.4.0. My PC is 64 bit windows 10.

I wanted to extract dataframes from PDF documents in R.

I tried to install tabulizer package using github but i am getting the following error.

```
> ghit::install_github(c("ropenscilabs/tabulizerjars", "ropenscilabs/tabulizer"), INSTALL_opts = "--no-multiarch")
also installing the dependencies ‘httpuv’, ‘sourcetools’

also installing the dependency ‘rJava’

ropenscilabs/tabulizerjars     ropenscilabs/tabulizer 
                        NA                         NA 
There were 14 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> library("tabulizer")
Error in library("tabulizer") : there is no package called ‘tabulizer’
```

The warnings were as follows,

```
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\akshay\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\akshay\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6RtCtU/downloaded_packages/httpuv_1.3.3.tar.gz' had status 1
2: In utils::install.packages(suggests, type = type, repos = repos,  ... :
  installation of package ‘httpuv’ had non-zero exit status
3: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\akshay\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\akshay\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6RtCtU/downloaded_packages/sourcetools_0.1.6.tar.gz' had status 1
4: In utils::install.packages(suggests, type = type, repos = repos,  ... :
  installation of package ‘sourcetools’ had non-zero exit status
5: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\akshay\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\akshay\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6RtCtU/downloaded_packages/shiny_1.0.3.tar.gz' had status 1
6: In utils::install.packages(suggests, type = type, repos = repos,  ... :
  installation of package ‘shiny’ had non-zero exit status
7: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\akshay\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\akshay\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6RtCtU/downloaded_packages/miniUI_0.1.1.tar.gz' had status 1
8: In utils::install.packages(suggests, type = type, repos = repos,  ... :
  installation of package ‘miniUI’ had non-zero exit status
9: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\akshay\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\akshay\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6RtCtU/downloaded_packages/rJava_0.9-8.tar.gz' had status 1
10: In utils::install.packages(to_install, type = type, repos = repos,  ... :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status
11: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\akshay\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\akshay\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6RtCtU/ghitdrat/src/contrib/tabulizerjars_0.9.2.tar.gz' had status 1
12: In utils::install.packages(to_install, type = type, repos = repos,  ... :
  installation of package ‘tabulizerjars’ had non-zero exit status
13: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\akshay\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\akshay\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6RtCtU/ghitdrat/src/contrib/tabulizer_0.1.24.tar.gz' had status 1
14: In utils::install.packages(to_install, type = type, repos = repos,  ... :
  installation of package ‘tabulizer’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: It doesn't look like there's enough info there to know what the problem is. After trying to install you should call `warnings()` like the error message suggests and see if it gives additional info.

Comment: I've included warnings in my question now

Comment: Okay, it looks like basically none of the needed packages installed correctly, so something is definitely going wrong. Do you have [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) installed? You should probably try installing some things one at a time like `install.packages("httpuv")` to isolate the problems.

Comment: The problem is resolved. I individually installed all the packages in the warnings section and then later i installed tabulizer. Now it's working fine. Thanks Marius!

Answer (score 5):

Most of the problems are cost by the 64 bit setting in your R session. If you want to use ‘tabulizer’ set the R session to 32 bit. If you are running a GUI, change the setting in there is the easiest way. If you are using e.g. R-studio see https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R.

After that run

`install.packages("remotes")` # get Package if you don’t have it

```
library(remotes)

remotes::install_github(c("ropensci/tabulizerjars", "ropensci/tabulizer"), INSTALL_opts = "--no-multiarch", dependencies = c("Depends", "Imports"))
```

If this results in errors install the packages one by one

`install.packages("plyr")` # get Package if you don’t have it

```
library(plyr)

packs <- c('stringi', 'httpuv', 'digest', 'htmltools', 'sourcetools', 'evaluate', 'markdown', 
           'stringr', 'yaml', 'rJava', 'testthat')

laply(packs, function(x){
  install.packages(x)  
  readline(prompt="Press [enter] to continue")
}
  )
```

If there are errors post them on Stack. If none of the packs gives an error (therefore the Press [enter] to continue), you can install tabulizer with

```
remotes::install_github(c("ropensci/tabulizerjars", "ropensci/tabulizer"), INSTALL_opts = "--no-multiarch", dependencies = c("Depends", "Imports"))
```

Comment: This returns: `leeper/tabulizerjars     leeper/tabulizer 
                  NA                   NA 
Warning messages:
1: In utils::install.packages(to_install, type = type, repos = repos,  :
  installation of package ‘tabulizerjars’ had non-zero exit status
2: In utils::install.packages(to_install, type = type, repos = repos,  :
  installation of package ‘tabulizer’ had non-zero exit status`

Comment: Try this  ghit::install_github(c("ropensci/tabulizerjars", "ropensci/tabulizer")) .  On GitHub ( https://github.com/ropensci/tabulizer#installation ) there is also an Installation section, inparticular the ( https://github.com/ropensci/tabulizer#installing-java-on-windows-with-chocolatey  ) section, because most of the instalation problems are caused by Java.