# Error using magick R to import PDF

Tags: r, pdf

I have hundreds of PDFs that I want to crop. For each PDF, I have a unique set of coordinates around which to crop. I am trying to use the R's magick package (version ImageMagick 6.9.9.14), but I receive an error when importing a PDF.

This example from the magick documentation throws an error:

```
 library(magick)
 manual <- image_read('https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/magick.pdf', density = "72x72")
```

The error I receive is "Error in magick_image_readpath(path, density, depth, strip) : Magick: PDFDelegateFailed `The system cannot find the file specified.
' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/809"

When I check the config settings:

```
magick_config
```

I find that ghostscript is true.  I am not sure if there are other settings required for reading in a PDF.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem with magick?  I am open to alternative packages with the ability to crop PDFs, if there are any.

Comment: I had the same problem on Windows. In my case, I sued ImageMagick 64 bit but had GhostScript 32-bit installed. After installing the 64-bit version it worked.

Comment: @MarkHeckmann where were you 6 days ago!?! This fixed my problem completely.  If you want to submit it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: haha, sorry, next time I will try to have the issue earlier ;) PS. I posted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem on Windows. It was no R problem. In my case, I used ImageMagick 64-bit but had GhostScript 32-bit installed. After installing the 64-bit version of GhostScript it worked without any issues.

Comment: This helped me, but I also had to install `pdftools` and I had to use `image_read_pdf` instead of `image_read`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tabulizer` package.

```
library(tabulizer)
manual_url <- "https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/magick.pdf" 
manual <- extract_text(manual_url)
```

For installing `tabulizer` follow exactly [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44147228/6574038).

Comment: tabulizer is a great package, but it doesn't really help here, because I am not interested in the text.  I am only interesting in trying to crop the images.  And loading the file with tabulizer doesn't produce a magick image object that the magick package can crop.