# Convert pdf to png with animation package

Tags: r, pdf, png

I am trying to convert [this example pdf](http://www.mediafire.com/file/f1ecy19mpdm88cy/Factura.pdf/file) to png using the animation package the same way it´s done here [Convert pdf to png in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617270/convert-pdf-to-png-in-r)

```
library("animation")
ani.options(outdir = "//Usuarios/Facturas")
pdf("Factura.pdf")
plot(1:10)
dev.off()
im.convert("Factura.pdf", 
           output = "Factura.png")
```

But I have this error:

[image: Error]

Same error than here: [Error using magick R to import PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48834749/error-using-magick-r-to-import-pdf) but that solution makes reference to an external software that I don´t find in the original post (and I haven´t installed). I red that Ghostscript do what I want (pdf to png), but isn´t what animation package suppose to do?

Or I messed up my brain?

Thanks

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617270/convert-pdf-to-png-in-r) might help.

Comment: This is the original post I said

Comment: If you do not have ImageMagick installed with Ghostscript delegate, then install it. If it is installed, then it could be an issue with the policy.xml file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861946/imagemagick-not-authorized-to-convert-pdf-to-an-image/52863413#52863413.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer with another package, I am gonna explain if someone need it.

```
library(pdftools)
library(magick)
fichero="Factura.pdf"
png= pdftools::pdf_convert(fichero, dpi = 600)
# And if someone want to read it
png2 = image_read(png)
```

This doesn´t save any file .png, which is a perfect solution for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

The `animation` package uses ImageMagick for some of its features (which is why ImageMagick is listed as a system requirement in [the manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/animation/animation.pdf)). ImageMagick in turn [apparently](http://imagemagick.sourceforge.net/http/www/windows.html) uses Ghostscript for PDF rendering. So yeah: the Ghostscript issues discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48834749/error-using-magick-r-to-import-pdf) are certainly worth looking into.