# pdftables R package throwing HTTP 400 error

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use pdftables package to extract data into csv.

```
install.packages("pdftables")
library(pdftables)

write.csv(head(iris), file = "test.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Open test.csv and print as PDF to "test.pdf"

```
convert_pdf("test.pdf", "test2.csv")
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> Error in get_content(input_file, format, api_key) :    Bad Request
>   (HTTP 400).

What's the fix here?

Comment: You want to convert a csv file to pdf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you get an API token?

To use the package the user first needs to sign up to the PDFTables API to get an API token (they offer a free package that allows up to 50 pages).

See: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pdftables/README.html

Comment: So, for more than 50 pages, we need to pay?

Answer (score 1):

To use the PDFTables R package, you need to the run the following command:

```
convert_pdf('test/index.pdf', output_file = NULL, format = "xlsx-single", message = TRUE, api_key = "insert_API_key")
```

Make sure you replace insert_API_key with your API key, and change the file path and/or format.

More info here: https://pdftables.com/blog/convert-pdf-to-excel-r