# R - Trouble installing tabular package

Tags: r, package, rjava, tabulizer

I'm trying to install the tabular package in order to pull tables from a pdf document.  I tried the solution outlined here: [Recognize PDF table using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141160/recognize-pdf-table-using-r), but I can't actually get all the precursor packages installed.  I got rJava installed fine, but when I ran "library(rJava)" I got the following message:

> Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>     call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
>     error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Documents/R/3.3.1/library/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
>     LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>   package ‘rJava’ was built under R version 3.3.3 
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’

I was able to install devtools as well, but when I ran "devtools::install_github("ropensci/tabulizer", args="--no-multiarch")", I got the following error message:

> Downloading GitHub repo ropensci/tabulizer@master
>   from URL https://api.github.com/repos/ropensci/tabulizer/zipball/master
>   Installing tabulizer
>   "C:/DOCUME~1/R/R-33~1.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD  \
>   INSTALL "C:/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpsteRkU/devtools2ac44b92539b/ropensci-tabulizer-bc195cb"  \
>   --library="C:/Documents/R/R-3.3.1/library" --install-tests --no-multiarch

Not sure what exactly is going on.  Thanks in advance for any direction here.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37735108/r-error-onload-failed-in-loadnamespace-for-rjava

Comment: Are you really running `R-3.3.1`? You are a few versions behind. Might want to also try upgrading to something more recent. (`R-3.5.1` is the current version).

Comment: Also that "Downloading GitHub repo..." isn't an error message. Does nothing happen after that message? Or does an actual error occur later?

Comment: Sorry, I cut the quote short:
ERROR: dependency 'tabulizerjars' is not available for package 'tabulizer'
* removing 'C:/Documents/R/R-3.3.1/library/tabulizer'
Installation failed: Command failed (1)

Comment: Got it. Thanks for pointing out the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I updated R to the latest version, downloaded 64 bit Java, added the new 64 bit Java to my PATH, and then the instructions from [Recognize PDF table using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141160/recognize-pdf-table-using-r) worked.