# Trying to resolve Java issue when running Tabulizer in R

Tags: java, r, tabulizer

I am trying to extract tables from pdfs in R using tabulizer, and keep getting this error when I use extract_tables.

`Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl, : java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class RJavaTools cannot access a member of class java.util.ArrayList$Itr (in module java.base) with modifiers "public"`

I have seen this question asked before and am aware that it is likely a dependency issue, but am unsure about how to fix that. I installed Maven and that hasn't seemed to work.

Comment: Which OS are you talking about? Have you considered my [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44147228/6574038)?

Comment: I am on Mac OS 10.13.6, and R 4.0.1. Tabulizer is no longer available to download by using install.packages, but I took a pretty similar approach by installing rJava first and then tabulizer from GitHub.

Comment: My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44147228/6574038) doesn't use `install.packages`, though. ;)

Comment: I get the same error. Could you solve this somehow?